# When increasing the amount of a single ingredient in bread, how do I calculate how much to increase the others?

Tags: bread

I have the bakers percentage formula from a recipe (Vienna bread from Bread Bakers Apprentice book). and the pre ferment came out a bit more than was indicated to be used in the recipe (19.3 oz instead of 13oz)

If the bakers percentages are as follows, how can I calculate how much to increase all the other ingredients to compensate for the extra pre ferment? (Note: I know a simple solution would be to just use 13oz of preferment by cutting away a portion of it, but I kind of just want to use it all up)

pre ferment 108% (13oz)

bread flour 100% (12oz)

sugar 4.2% (0.5oz)

malt powder 2.1% (0.25oz)

salt 2.1% (0.25oz)

yeast .92% (0.11oz)

egg 13.8% (1.65oz)

butter 4.2% (0.5oz)

water 54.2% (6 to 7 oz)

Answer (score 8):

The key is that the **percentages** remain unchanged - they simply give the various *ratios* of the ingredients based on the flour weight.

What you need to adjust is the **absolute weighs** by the same factor you changed one ingredient, and that factor in your case is calculated by the (amount of preferment you intend to use)/(amount of preferment in the original recipe):

> 19.3 oz / 13 oz = 1,48

So you multiply all ingredients by 1,48 (or 1.5 if you are so inclined) and proceed as usual.

---

Note that the same principle applies to scaling of all kinds of recipes that give weights or volumes for the ingredients, because the underlying principle of (ingredients are used in a certain ratio) is the same.